# Firefox: Applying border/outline CSS properties to SVG elements

Tags: css, firefox, svg

Firefox seems to fully ignore `border` and `outline` CSS properties defined for SVG elements. The SVG group elements , `<g>`, in my case, are used to group composite elements into a single logical element to simplify user interaction in my app. The following code works really good in Chrome:

```svg
<svg>
    <g>
        <rect x="10" y="10" width="50" height="50" fill="yellow"></rect>
        <rect x="20" y="20" width="30" height="30" fill="yellowgreen"></rect>
    </g>
</svg>
```

```css
g:hover {
    outline: dashed 4px red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QQRPj/

In Chrome, once you move the mouse pointer over the group of two rectangles, the group gets a red dashed rectangle around it. However, I can't make it work in Firefox, despite it seems to support more simple CSS properties like `cursor`, `display`, and SVG-related properties like it's [described at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/SVG_and_CSS).

Is there any opportunity to make `outline` and `border` CSS properties work in Firefox, so a CSS change could be the only effective patch instead of patching SVG-related code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SVG specification has a list of [all CSS properties that are valid for SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/propidx.html) border and outline are not in that list and therefore do not apply to SVG. You should raise a [blink bug](http://crbug.com/new)

If you want a border or outline in SVG you'll have to put a `<rect>` round the object and calculate that `<rect>` position using getBBox if necessary. In the above case you could put the hover on the outer `<svg>` element as that is a replaced element and does get border and outline properties because of that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the suggestion for `getBBox()`. Regarding the example at JsFiddle, if I understood you right: that CSS rule marks any `<g>` as hoverable, not entire `<svg>` container (just put another group).